# Solve Fredholm equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Solve the Fredholm integral equation

$$w(x)=x+ k \int_0^1 \left( x^{\frac{1}{2}} t^{\frac{3}{2}}+x^{\frac{3}{2}} t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) w(t)dt$$

That is what I have been thinking:

Mostly, the solution of Fredholm equations is  obtained by the method of successive approximations.

In our case, no information of $y$ is given. I don;t know any other way to find the solution. I would be grateful if you provide me with some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation as
$$
w(x) = x + kAx^{1/2} + kBx^{3/2},
$$
where
\begin{align}
A &= \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d} t ~ t^{3/2}w(t) \\
B &= \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d} t ~ t^{1/2}w(t).
\end{align}
Multiplyng both sides of the first equation by $t^{3/2}$ and integrate over $x$, you obtain
\begin{align}
A &= \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d} x ~ x^{5/2} + kA\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d} x ~ x^{2} + kB \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d} x ~ x^{3} \\
&= \frac{2}{7} + \frac{kA}{3} + \frac{kB}{4}.
\end{align}
In the same way,
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{2}{5} + \frac{kA}{2} + \frac{kB}{3}.
\end{align}
Solving these two equations, you find
\begin{align}
A &= -\frac{12}{35}\frac{k+60}{k^{2}+48k-72} \\
B &= -\frac{24}{35}\frac{k+42}{k^{2}+48k-72},
\end{align}
and you obtain $w(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this case is known as "degenerate" Fredholm equation. Observe that
$$
w(x)=x+ k \int_0^1 \left( x^{\frac{1}{2}} t^{\frac{3}{2}}+x^{\frac{3}{2}} t^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) w(t)dt = x + k x^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^1 t^{\frac{3}{2}} w(t) dt + k x^{\frac{3}{2}} \int_0^1 t^{\frac{1}{2}} w(t) dt
$$
As $k$, $\int_0^1 t^{\frac{3}{2}} w(t) dt$ and $\int_0^1 t^{\frac{1}{2}} w(t) dt$ are constants, the only possible form of $w(t)$ is $w(x) = x + A x^{\frac{1}{2}} + B x^{\frac{3}{2}}$, where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$. So, you can substitute it in the equation to detemine $A$ and $B$:
$$
x + A x^{\frac{1}{2}} + B x^{\frac{3}{2}} = x + k x^{\frac{1}{2}}
\int_0^1 t^{\frac{3}{2}} \left(t + A t^{\frac{1}{2}} + B t^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) dt +
k x^{\frac{3}{2}}
\int_0^1 t^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(t + A t^{\frac{1}{2}} + B t^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) dt
$$
It leads to system of linear equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
A = k \int_0^1 t^{\frac{3}{2}} \left(t + A t^{\frac{1}{2}} + B t^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) dt \\
B = k \int_0^1 t^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(t + A t^{\frac{1}{2}} + B t^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) dt
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
A = k \left( \int_0^1 t^\frac{5}{2} dt + A \int_0^1 t^2 dt + B \int_0^1 t^3 dt\right) \\
B = k \left( \int_0^1 t^\frac{3}{2} dt + A \int_0^1 t dt + B \int_0^1 t^2 dt\right)
\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
A = k \left( \frac{2}{7} + \frac{1}{3} A + \frac{1}{4}B\right) \\
B = k \left( \frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{2} A + \frac{1}{3}B\right)
\end{cases}
$$
According to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A%20%3D%20k%20*%20%282%2F7%20%2B%201%2F3%20*%20A%20%2B%201%2F4%20*%20B%29%2C%20B%20%3D%20k%20*%20%282%2F5%20%2B%201%2F2%20*%20%20A%20%2B%201%2F3%20*%20B%29%20solve%20for%20A%2C%20B), it leads to
$$
A = -\frac{12}{35} \frac{k^2 + 60k}{k^2 + 48k - 72},
B = -\frac{24}{35} \frac{k^2 + 42k}{k^2 + 48k - 72}
$$
So, if $k^2 + 48k - 72 \neq 0$, solution is given by
$$
w(x) = x -\frac{12}{35} \frac{k^2 + 60k}{k^2 + 48k - 72} x^\frac{1}{2}
 - \frac{24}{35} \frac{k^2 + 42k}{k^2 + 48k - 72} x^\frac{3}{2}
$$
otherwise (if $k = -24 \pm 18 \sqrt{2}$) there is no solution.